# how to clear background of child control windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I am having a `Grid` with background color. `ScrollViewer` is first children of `Grid`.
`ScrollViewer` gets its background same as parent.

**Problem:** Background of `ScrollViewer` is not required, Is there any way to get rid of it?

**Code:**

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Bisque">
        <ScrollViewer Height="500" Width="300" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

I tried setting ScrollViewer's `Background=Transparent`, but didn't work.

Comment: so wht is the problem ? do you need scrollviwer background as same background or no background or different background from grid. please be clear

Comment: no background inside ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 2):

**ScrollViewer** has a Background as **Transparent** **by default** so any color you would set in **Parent (Grid)** Background would be **Background color** of it

so In your case you would be needed to set Background as your need of color else it would be Transparent . The Background color of **Parent (Grid)** would be seen in its content as it has **Transparent Background**.